# How can I make an animation within a shell script?

Tags: bash

I've recently started coding and made this coin flip code. Now I want to make an animation for it but I have no clue how to make such an animation. Does anyone have any ideas how I start making this? What programs?

I haven't tried anything yet, but this is the code used for the coin flip.

```
printf "(H) heads or (T) tails"
read user_choice
if [ $user_choice != H ] && [ $user_choice != T ]; then
  echo invalid choice defaulting to heads
 $user_choice=H=1
 $user_choice=T=2
fi
#value of 1 is heads, 2 is Tails
computer_choice=$(($RANDOM% 2 + 1))
if [ $computer_choice == 1 ]; then
  echo computer chooses heads
elif [ $computer_choice == 2 ]; then
echo computer chooses tails
fi
if [ $computer_choice == 1 ] && [ $user_choice = H ]; then
  echo you win!
else
if [ $computer_choice == 2 ] && [ $user_choice = T ]; then
    echo you win!
  else
    echo you lose
  fi
fi
```

Comment: What kind of animation? ASCII art? Bash scripts and animation don't normally go together...

Comment: @JohnKugelman they don't? i just want this coin to spin once or twice. and then land on a big H or T

Comment: What kind of animation? ASCII art?

Comment: @JohnKugelman i don't know... maybe? this is going to be the first time i'll actually try to make an animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Walter A's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

# begin config
minsteps=12
maxsteps=20
sleepytime=0.2
# end config

frames=(
    '  |  '
    ' ( ) '
    '( S )'
 )

sides=(H T)

side=$(($RANDOM % 2))

read -r -p "(H) heads or (T) tails" user_choice

user_choice=${user_choice^^}    # upper case the input (not available in Bash 3.2)

if [[ $user_choice == H ]]
then
    user_choice=0
elif [[ $user_choice == T ]]
then
    user_choice=1
else
    printf '%s\n' "invalid choice, defaulting to heads"
    user_choice=0
fi

for (( step = 0; step < maxsteps; step++ ))
do
    for (( frame = 0; frame < 3; frame++ ))
    do
        if (( frame == 2 ))
        then
            f=${frames[frame]/S/${sides[side]}}    # swap H or T for S (template char)
            computer_choice=$side
            (( side ^= 1 ))    # toggle H/T
        else
            f=${frames[frame]}
        fi
        printf '\r%s' "$f"
        # if showing a side and some flips have taken place and a 50% chance
        if (( frame == 2 && step > minsteps && RANDOM > 16383 ))
        then
            break 2    # exit both loops, we're done
        fi
        sleep "$sleepytime"
    done
done

printf '\n'

if [[ $user_choice == $computer_choice ]]
then
  printf '%s\n' "you win!"
else
  printf '%s\n' "you lose"
fi
```

Comment: this almost works, but it always lands on T somehow

Comment: The first test of RANDOM should give 50% T. The second test should have 50% of the remainder (so 25%) value H. I would expect about 67% times 'T'.

Comment: You might start with `site=$(($RANDOM % 2))`.

Comment: @WalterA: What second test? But your suggestion of starting in an initial random state fixes the problem. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good that the fix worked. FYI When `step>minsteps`, the test `if (( frame == 2 && step > minsteps && RANDOM > 16383 ))` can be called more than once. The second time this test is called can also result in a `RANDOM <=16383`. The first site H/T shown is most likely to  cause a break.

Comment: You can start with a random `site` and a random `computer_choice` and calculate where to stop flipping. Or use `RANDOM % (maxsteps - minsteps + 1)` when to stop flipping.

Comment: so i've added this with the comments and now have a functional coin flip, but the resluts of the coin is not similar to $computer_choice and i don't know where or how to fix that (i've only been coding for about a month now) so how can i make the result of my coinflip animation similar to $computer_choice?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "similar to `$computer_choice`, but the equivalent to what you're doing in the script in your question is in the `$side` variable in my script. I'll add some code to complete my script to include the user selection and the test for win/loss. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to have all frames of the animation in a separate text file (see [here](https://github.com/hugomd/parrot.live/tree/master/frames) for an example). 
Then what you simply do is:

- for each of the frames:

  - clear the screen and draw the current frame

See [this](https://github.com/hugomd/parrot.live) for more details: https://github.com/hugomd/parrot.live

Answer (score 1):

simple animation:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do
   printf "\r  |  "
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r ( )  "
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r( H )"
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r ( )  "
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r  |  "
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r ( )  "
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r( T ) "
   sleep 0.2
   printf "\r ( )  "
   sleep 0.2
done
```

EDIT:
When you want to remove the coin from the output when finished, add

```
printf "\r    \r"
```

after the loop.
When you want to randomly finish on T or H, add

```
   if (( $RANDOM % 2 )); then
      printf "\r( H )\n"
      computer_choice=1
   else
      printf "\r( T )\n"
      computer_choice=2
   fi
```

after the loop.

Comment: the animation itself works fine, but you end up with a blank space between the brackets and a questionmark behind it

Comment: I added some code you can use after the loop.
You might want to change the "graphics" with `:-)` and ` $ ` for H and T.

Answer (score 1):

the correct code:

```
printf "(H) heads or (T) tails"
read user_choice
if [ $user_choice != H ] && [ $user_choice != T ]; then
  echo invalid choice defaulting to heads
 $user_choice=H
 $user_choice=T
fi
#value of 1 is heads, 2 is Tails
# begin config
minsteps=6
maxsteps=10
sleepytime=0.125
# end config

frames=(
    '  |  '
    ' ( ) '
    '( S )'
 )

sides=(H T)

side=$(($RANDOM% 2 ))

for (( step = 0; step < maxsteps; step++ ))
do
   for (( frame = 0; frame < 3; frame++ ))
    do
        if (( frame == 2 ))
        then
            f=${frames[frame]/S/${sides[side]}}    # swap H or T for S (templat$
            (( side ^= 1 ))    # toggle H/T
        else
            f=${frames[frame]/S/${sides[side]}}
            (( side ^= 2 ))    # toggle H/T
        fi
        printf '\r%s' "$f"
        # if showing a side and some flips have taken place and a 50% chance
        if (( frame == 2 && step > minsteps && RANDOM > 16383 ))
        then
            break 2    # exit both loops, we're done
        fi
        sleep "$sleepytime"
    done
done

printf '\n'
if [ ${sides[side]} == T ] && [ $user_choice = H ]; then
  echo you win!
else
if [ ${sides[side]} == H ] && [ $user_choice = T ]; then
    echo you win!
  else
    echo you lose
  fi
fi

printf  "would you like to play again? (Y) or (N)"
read Y_N
if [ $Y_N == Y ]; then
exec bash coin.sh
else
echo ok good bye
fi
```